# How to reach each individual json object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I recieve post request

```
{
  "event_type": "IncomingCallEnd",
  "account_id": 55555,
  "did_num": "88001234567",
  "did": "7123456789",
  "call_id": "1588984514.9676405",
  "abon": "103",
  "billsec": "19",
  "secret": "4ff8rZbTZ0TllXL"
}
```

I encode it

```
 $jsonString = $json;
 $call = json_decode($jsonString);
```

I want to reach object `did_num` in order to replace 1st digit in it

```
$call->did_num = substr_replace(trim(urldecode($_POST["did_num"])),'7',0,1);
```

I tried this

```
$call = json_decode($jsonString, TRUE);
```

but didn't reach `did_num`
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for replies

Comment: Welcome. What do you mean by "I didn't reach `did_num`"? What's wrong exactly? Your code seems fine: https://3v4l.org/cXucq.

Comment: Why did you reload $call?  If you do that then $call->did_num is erased

Comment: @Jeto I mean that `did_num` returns empty value

Comment: @Forbes I mean that I try both
`$jsonString = $json;
 $call = json_decode($jsonString);`
and
`$jsonString = $json;
 $call = json_decode($jsonString, TRUE);`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.
Instead of using
`$call->did_num = substr_replace(trim(urldecode($_POST["did_num"])),'7',0,1);`
I use
`$call->did_num = substr_replace(trim($call->did_num),'7',0,1);`
https://3v4l.org/PIe8U

Comment: simpler: https://3v4l.org/ME2U4